# Finding $\int\left(\frac{x}{\cos\left(x\right)+x\csc x}\right)^2\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Consider the integral

$$\int\left(\dfrac{x}{\cos\left(x\right)+x\csc x}\right)^2\,dx$$

How to start integrating?
Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Usually replacing trigonometric functions by their exponential equivalence works. Have you tried $cos(x) = \frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}$, and $csc(x)$ the same way?

Comment: and without using complex substitution?

Comment: I would not need that substitution, Generally I integrate w.r.t the variable $x$ after these replacements. You should give it a try.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can write this as

$$ \int \dfrac{x^2 \sin^2(x)}{(x + \sin(x)\cos(x))^2} $$
Now since
$$ \dfrac{d}{dx} \dfrac{1}{x + \sin(x) \cos(x)} = - 2 \dfrac{\cos^2 x}{(x+\sin(x)\cos(x))^2}$$
integrate by parts with $$u = \dfrac{x^2 \sin^2(x)}{\cos^2(x)},\ dv = \dfrac{\cos^2(x)\; dx}{(x + \sin(x)\cos(x))^2}$$  After a miraculous simplification, you end up looking at 
$$ \ldots + \int \dfrac{x \sin(x)\; dx}{\cos^3 (x)}$$
which yields to another integration by parts.